# git commit SHA hash in environment variable in ember-cli

Tags: javascript, ember-cli, build-tools, broccolijs

How to expose the latest git commit SHA hash in an environment variable in `config/environment.js` in **ember-cli**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found a solution with `ember-cli-app-version`

https://www.npmjs.com/package/ember-cli-app-version

> so will get git hash in `{{app-version}}` helper. This addon will
>   automatically append SHA to the end of the version.

`HTMLBAR` template can use like

`{{app-version shaOnly=true}}` // git SHA